# a guy about to get married disapear?

Tags: word-usage, parts-of-speech

In my book there is the text:

> A thousand thoughts went through my mind. It was another mystery and right in our old hometown. **Why would a guy about to get married disappear**?
>
> Maybe he'd gotten cold feet and was a runaway groom.

I am interested in "Why would a guy about to get married disappeared?". It's interrogative and I think affirmative should be "A guy would about to get married disappeared". Am I right?

And how do English people know which is "about" part of speech - adjective, preposition or adverbs (in my case)?

Comment: Please tell us _which_ book! I think you have copied the sentence wrongly - it would make sense as **Why would a guy about to get married disappear?** (Note the spelling.) It means 'a man **who is** about to get married' see [this definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-about-to).

Comment: Yes it was my mistake. Why would a guy about to get married disappear? - correct.    Book is "Red Rock Mysteries Series", Windy City Danger,

Answer (score 2):

"Why would a guy about to get married disappeared?" is not grammatical. The word "disappear" should be the bare infinitive, not the past tense. A corrected version would be "Why would a guy about to get married *disappear*?" The same applies to the affirmative: it would be "A guy about to get married would *disappear*."

Answer (score 0):

The affirmative would be **A guy [who was] about to get married disappeared.** (*Would* in the question refers to his reason for doing so.)

A native speaker would recognise that *about to* is a common adjective phrase, as explained [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-about-to).

PS It's best to give the author and title of a book you are referring to: *Windy City Danger* by Jerry B. Jenkins and Chris Fabry.